# Export to 32-bit instead of 16-bit Web Audio API

Tags: wav, web-audio-api, 32-bit

I'm using the web audio API to apply effects and export a file. It works great, but I would like to export the file at 32 bit instead of 16.

How could I alter the below settings to achieve this?

```
  setUint32(0x46464952); // "RIFF"
  setUint32(length - 8); // file length - 8
  setUint32(0x45564157); // "WAVE"

  setUint32(0x20746d66); // "fmt " chunk
  setUint32(16); // length = 16
  setUint16(1); // PCM (uncompressed)
  setUint16(numOfChan);
  setUint32(abuffer.sampleRate);
  setUint32(abuffer.sampleRate * 2 * numOfChan); // avg. bytes/sec
  setUint16(numOfChan * 2); // block-align
  setUint16(16); 

  setUint32(0x61746164); // "data" - chunk
  setUint32(length - pos - 4); // chunk length

  // write interleaved data
  for (i = 0; i < abuffer.numberOfChannels; i++)
    channels.push(abuffer.getChannelData(i));

  while (pos < length) {
    for (i = 0; i < numOfChan; i++) {
      // interleave channels
      sample = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, channels[i][offset])); // clamp
      sample = (0.5 + sample < 0 ? sample * 32768: sample * 32767) | 0;
      view.setInt16(pos, sample, true); // update data chunk
      pos += 2;
    }
    offset++; // next source sample
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea is simple.  Convert the float to an Uint32 by using an array view.  Then write out the uint32 values instead of int16 values. No clipping is needed.  And be sure to output the correct wav header for the changed length and format type.

I know Chromium has some code to do this for WebAudio testing.  But you'll have to abide by Chromium licenses to use it.